# Using SSMS - if you have a large list of servers... is there a tip to use a search function to find a "string" in the list of registered servers

Tags: ssms

Like looking for all of my *DEX* servers?   As opposed to looking/scrolling thru them all.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS doesn't offer search capabilities in the Registered Servers.

If you're using a Central Management Server (CMS), my open source [DBA Database](https://github.com/amtwo/dba-database) includes [a view](https://github.com/amtwo/dba-database/blob/production/views/dbo.CmsServers.sql) to expose registered servers to be easily queried via T-SQL.

After installing the DBA Database (or the solitary view), you can simply connect to the CMS using a query window and do a search like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.CmsServers
WHERE ServerName LIKE '%DEX%';
```

The view also exposes group membership and the full hierarchy at a path so you can do something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.CmsServers
WHERE ServerName LIKE '%DEX%'
AND ServerPath LIKE '%Production%';
```

If you're using locally registered servers, you would have to migrate those connections to a CMS to use the view. Thankfully, even Express Edition can be used as a CMS to save on licensing costs.